# Exclude users from remarketing ads

Tags: google-ads

How can I use a snippet of JavaScript in my site to exclude users from my remarketing campaigns/ads in the future?

The idea is to avoid showing remarketing ads to users that performed certain actions in the website. I know this can be done when the user visits specific URLS, but I would need to do it with user actions that don't have a specific URL, but can be detected with JavaScript.

Can it be done making the user run a different Adwords remarketing tag? How?

Comment: Detect _what_ with JS?

Comment: @w3dk Detect user actions on my site like for example the click on a button. For example I would like users that clicked a certain button on my to stop seeing my remarketing ads.

Comment: a certain button on my site, of course.